# Comparing strings stored in array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, string, object, string-comparison

I am trying to sort a list of names alphabetically using insertion sort and to do that I require to compare two arrays of objects however when I use the standard string library function `compare` the complier interprets this as if I would like to access the data member of my class when in fact I want to access the data member of the class that holds the string.

```
void Course::sortRow(int RowtoSort)
{
    int i, j;

    Student bucket; 

    for(i = 1; i < enrolled[RowtoSort];i++)
    {
        //assign bucket with temp value for swap
        bucket = Students[RowtoSort][i]; 

        for(j = i;
            (j > 0) && (Students[RowtoSort][j-1].compare(bucket)) < 0;
            j--) //how would I compare the two arrays of objects?
            {
                //assign j to element j-1 so now both j and j-1
                // are the same in the array
                Students[RowtoSort][j] = Students[RowtoSort][j-1]; 
            }

            //now j-1 value is at j and since j-- assign it
            // to bucket to place the proper value at j-1  
            Students[RowtoSort][j] = bucket;
        } // end outer loop
    }
```

How would I go about comparing the two objects `Students[RowtoSort][i]` with Bucket?

Comment: Scratches head ... OK lets start at the beginning ... Why does sorting a list of names alphabetically (it seems like a simple thing to do) require you to compare two arrays of objects?

Comment: The program gets it's data of students from plain text and uses it to fill an array of student objects. The Students array is a 2D array which holds 45 students for each row (3)

Comment: So it seems that you are trying to sort one row in your 2D array of Students. And presumably you are sorting those by name? I think all you need to do is this `Students[RowtoSort][j-1].name.compare(bucket.name))` I'm assuming that the 'data member that holds the string' is called `name`, but if it isn't then replace `name` with whatever you have called it.

Comment: mb a little odd question: why the name of a variable i.e. `Students` starts with a capital?

Comment: `Students[RowtoSort][j-1]` this is an object as far as I understand i.e. your are using `std::string::compare` on an object and "feed" `bucket` to it which is of type `Student`. [std::string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)